# No such module 'InputBarAccessoryView'

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, messagekit

Trying to get MessageKit setup within my project.  I'm getting the following error - 'No such module 'InputBarAccessoryView' within the

```
MessagesViewController+Keyboard.swift:26:8: No such module 'InputBarAccessoryView'
```

I've tried installing pods, updating pods and deintegrating.

```
import Foundation
import InputBarAccessoryView
```

Should compile normally. Only error that persists.

Comment: Is this part of `MessageKit`? You may have to import as `import MessageKit.InputBarAccessoryView`

Comment: this is a part of MessageKit.  Let me give it a try.  Thanks Jake for responding.

Comment: Now I'm getting 'No such module 'MessageKit.InputBarAccessoryView''.  I've been working on it for over a week and can't resolve it.

Comment: @jake any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In My case i will update pod file Ios version

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'

target 'Messanger' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Messanger

pod 'InputBarAccessoryView'

end
```